# scrollTop: Smooth scroll to ID interferes with back to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a jQuery novice. I have two functions on the same page:

- one which is a smooth scroll to an ID
- the other which shows a "back to top" element after the user scrolls a set distance.

The functions work on their own, but **when I combine them as shown below, the "back to top" function doesn't work.**

I think I'm missing something obvious and could use some help.
Thanks!

---

**Update:** This fiddle shows the problem:

[back to top jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcw/Nw5Uu/)
If the smooth scroll block is disabled, the back to top function works.

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  //smooth scrolling
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top -150}, 900, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;});
  });

// Show or hide the back to top footer button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('.go-top').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $('.go-top').fadeOut(200);
    }
  });

  // Animate the scroll to top
  $('.go-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 900);
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi there, just a quick note that it's always nice to really make your question more readily accessible to the developers  here by building a quick JSFiddle, link: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are u using just a `#` character as the `.go-top` 's `href` like `<a class="go-top" href="#">...</a>` ?

Comment: I'm guessing your `.go-top` link has an invalid `href'. Try replacing it with `<a class="go-top" href="top">` and see if it works.

Comment: Yes @Batu Zet, my go top is `<a href="#" class="go-top" title="Go to the top of the page">Back to top of page</a>

Comment: @DavidCara then do as @kayen suggested. Your `$('a[href^="#"]').on('click')` function works for every a has `#` in its `href` and that causes an error for your go to top link.

Comment: instead of `href="#"` try `href="javascript:void(0)"` on your go to top link

Comment: Thanks for the comments - they were very helpful. Interestingly @Ennui's suggestion worked on jsfiddle but not on the relevant WordPress site. I accepted TechYogi's answer because it was the first working answer. I'm new to stack overflow so hope this is OK. Cheers

Comment: @DavidCara was your go to top link in a template or added via post content?  If it was in the post content somewhere the JS probably was stripped out.

Comment: Hi @Ennui, it was added in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @DavidCara Just add

```
<div id="top"></div>
```

after immediate `<body>` tag it'll defiantly work.

See updated jsfiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yogeshlt/Nw5Uu/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it works, but I'm a bit reticent about adding an empty div!

Comment: I know but same problem I faced on one of my recent project and this seems to be a fix for me. But If you don't want to add empty div just make it `<div id="top">Back to Top</div>` and make it hidden with css :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code in html tags directly.

```
 <a onclick="$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 900);" href="javascript:;">back to top </a>
```